# Consuming webservices with field of type cdata

Tags: java, xml, web-services, cxf, cdata

I'm consuming a web service using CXF, the thing is that I need to send and XML inside a CDATA tag.
To do it I created an interceptor

```
public class CDATAInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>            {

    public CDATAInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
        //addAfter(AttachmentOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        message.put("disable.outputstream.optimization", Boolean.TRUE);
        XMLStreamWriter writer = (XMLStreamWriter)     message.getContent(XMLStreamWriter.class);
        if (writer != null && !(writer instanceof CDataXMLStreamWriter)) {
            message.setContent(XMLStreamWriter.class, new CDataXMLStreamWriter(writer));
        }
    }

    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
        System.out.println(messageParam);
    }    
}
```

I am using a custom CDATAXMLStreamWriter defined as follows:

```
public class CDataXMLStreamWriter extends DelegatingXMLStreamWriter {

    private static final Pattern XML_CHARS = Pattern.compile( "[&<>]" );

    public CDataXMLStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter del) { 
        super(del);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException { 
        boolean useCData = XML_CHARS.matcher( text ).find();
        if (useCData) { 
            super.writeCData(text);
        }else { 
            super.writeCharacters(text); 
        } 
    }

    public void writeStartElement(String local) throws XMLStreamException { 
        super.writeStartElement(local); 
    } 
}
```

I configured this CDATA interceptor as follows

```
protected void configureCDataInterceptor() {
    CDATAInterceptor inter = new CDATAInterceptor();
    ClientProxy.getClient(this.clientProxy).getOutInterceptors().add(inter);
}
```

The issue I have is that the xml inside CDATA is splitted in multiple parts, somthing like this

```
<![CDATA[part1ofXML]]><![CDATA[part2ofXML]]><![CDATA[part3ofXML]]>
```

I tried getting the XML and removing all the newline characters and the XML gets inside one CDATA block, but the issue with this is that this XML is signed, and removing the characters breaks the signature.

I hope this was clear enough, and sorry if the post is hard to understand.
If you can give me one clue to solve this problem it would be great!

Thanks,
Julio

Comment: Why do you "need to send and XML inside a CDATA tag"? Whether escaped XML or unescaped CDATA, it's XML and any XML reader should read it correctly.

Comment: Anyway, if you get multiple consecutive calls to `writeCharacters()`, i.e. the text is not coalesced, and you want the text to be combined into a *single* CDATA block, then you must accumulate all the text from the multiple calls to `writeCharacters()` or `writeCData()` and flush it on *any* other call. In short, it's up to you to coalesce the text.

Comment: Adding it in a Cdata block is part of the specification of the server side of the web service, don't ask me why, it should be the same.
I'll try to do what you told me tomorrow.